# Iterating over two dimension array and knowing current position

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I am trying to iterate a multidimension array created with the following line

To iterate i'm using the following code

```
visiblematrix= Array.new (10) {Array.new(10){0}}
```

But this doesn't allow me to know the current x,y position while iterating. how can i find it out without resorting to temporary variables

```
visiblematrix.each do |x|
            x.each do |y|
                  puts y
            end 
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `each_index` instead of just `each`.

Keep in mind x and y would now be your index not the value at that index.  So visiblematrix[x] etc.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method (ruby arrays include the Enumerable mixin).

```
visiblematrix.each_with_index do |x, xi|
  x.each_with_index do |y, yi|
    puts "element [#{xi}, #{yi}] is #{y}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I like when I learn something even when I try to help others.